# Can a combobox control hosted in DataGridView cell ask to end edit?

Tags: .net, datagridview

I have a combobox control hosted in a unbound DataGridView control. When the user selects an item (or types an entry and hits enter) I want it to apply the change and come out of edit mode.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event of your DataGridView, you can call the following code:

```
myDataGridView.EndEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do :

```
 datagridview1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
```

if you want to not end edit and your value to be committed.